# Safari makes os freeze

Tags: macos, safari, performance

I have a Mid-2014 MBP retina 15" running `OSX 10.11.5`. It runs flawlessly except for occasional Safari freezes. It happens only while I'm using Safari, and mostly when I try to close a tab. I've contacted Apple support multiple times, and they advised me to try a few things, none of which worked. I've tried to following:

- cleared history
- deleted cashes in `~/Library/caches` and `/Library/caches/`

When it freezes, everything freezes with absolutely no response, so I have to do a hard reset every time. What could be the problem? How can I diagnose the problem and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

In Preferences (<kbd>cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>)

**Privacy:**

1. Check: Allow from websites I visit.
2. Remove all website data..
3. Prompt for each website one time only
4. Ask websites not to track me

**Notifications:**

Remove all

**Extensions:**

Disable them all for now.

**Search:**

Untick all and only tick: Enable quick website search

---

Quit (<kbd>cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) and re-open the app. Let us know if it happens again? :)

Comment: May or may not work, but an answer is better than no answer. :)

Comment: Hey, thanks. I've been trying this for a couple of days, hasn't frozen yet. It kind of slows down after a while, though. Specifically, when I try to select the address bar either by clicking on it, or doing `Cmd+L`, it hangs for a second or so, and then lets me type.

Comment: The same is true for opening a new tab with the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: So it gets slower by time until you clear cache again? Thnks for Cmnd+L never knew about it! hehe

Comment: It doesn't get linearly slower. Sometimes it's slower, sometimes it's working fine. I'm inclined to think it's a RAM issue, but every other app works fine, and it's only Safari that creates problems.

Comment: Search for FreeMemory on Mac AppStore, makes space if theres none and u can check how much free RAM u got etc.

Comment: Thanks. I can already check this using activity monitor -- but isn't it weird that it's only safari that freezes? Also, I'm sure the OS has better ways of handling the situation if the system runs out of RAM: freezing up entirely is so 90s :)